# How to compile all the tex files in a directory

Tags: command-line, latex

I have a few tens of .tex files in a directory.

How can I compile them all with a single command from the terminal?

Moreover: is it possible to avoid all the files that are generated by the compiler (.bak, .log, .aux, .out, .bib files)?

I usually compile with `pdflatex file.tex`.

Comment: It will be easier to answer for your needs, if you'll detail how do you compile one tex file from the terminal.

Comment: @Yaron I have added the command I usually use

Comment: @Melebius the compiler generally produces .bak, .log, .aux, .out, .bib files. I would like to have only the .tex and .pdf files in my directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `for` command

```
for f in *.tex; do pdflatex $f; done
```

I find this syntax easier to remember than find.

Regarding deleting auxiliary files consider using `latexmk -c -pdf` or `latexmk -C -pdf` instead of `pdflatex`. `latexmk` is latex make, which builds only the files that need to be built. I am not sure, which auxiliary files get deleted exactly, but I think most of them will be deleted with `-c` or `-C` switch.

```
for f in *.tex; do latexmk -C -pdf $f; done
```

According to manual it should also work like this

```
latexmk -C -pdf *.tex
```

Another option would be to delete files manually after the processing is done. That would be accomplished like this:

```
for f in *.tex; do pdflatex $f; done; rm *.bak *.log *.aux *.out *.bib
```

I am not sure if this still qualifies for a oneliner.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`man pdflatex`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/pdflatex.1.html), it only accepts one file. Such commands can be run on more files using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.tex' -exec pdflatex {} \;
```

- The `.` parameter tells `find` to search in the current folder.
- `-maxdepth 1` disables recursion to subfolders – remove this if not needed.
- `-name '*.tex'` allows processing just the `*.tex` files.
- `-exec` runs the given command (`pdflatex`) with each found file and replaces `{}` with the actual filename. `\;` ends the `-exec` option and marks that only one found file should be passed to each `pdflatex` call.

You can test the command by including `echo` between `-exec` and `pdflatex`. In this case, the resulting commands `find` will be just printed to the standard output.

After the process, you can simply remove the unwanted files using the `rm` command, for example:

```
rm *.bak *.log *.aux *.out *.bib
```